# Showing that a critical point becomes unstable at a certain value of another parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, bifurcation

Say I have the following first-order system for $n$:

$$
\dot{n} = \frac{Gnp}{Gn+f} - kn,
$$

where $G$, $f$, and $k$ are always positive, but $p$ can take either sign.

First, I want to find the critical points $n^*$ of this system.  One is obviously $n^*=0$.  I can solve for the other one to get $n^*=\frac{pG-fk}{Gk}$.  Further algebraic rearrangements reveal that the second critical point is negative if $p<\frac{fk}{G}=p_c$ and positive if $p > p_c$.

What should I do to show that $n^*=0$ becomes unstable for $p>p_c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the stability of a fixed point $n^{*}$ of the system $\dot{n} = f(n)$ by checking its derivative at $n^{*}$.

If $f^{'}(n^{*}) < 0$, then $n^*$ is a stable fixed point.  If $f^{'}(n^{*}) > 0$, the fixed point will be unstable.  For $f^{'}(n^{*}) = 0$, we cannot tell whether the fixed point is stable or unstable and have to get another case.

Here, using the quotient rule, we can calculate $f^{'}(n) = \frac{1}{(Gn + f)^{2}} [(Gn + f)Gp - (Gnp)G]-k$.
For unstabilty check for two fixed points ,

$case-1 :$

when $$  n^{*} = \frac{pG - fk}{Gk}$$

$f^{'}(n) = \frac{Gp}{(Gn + f)} - \frac{G^{2}np}{(Gn + f)^2} - k > 0$
So we have three terms above , if we workout for first term it comes out as $k$ and this cancels out with the $-k$ (the third term) , so we are only left with $-\frac{G^{2}np}{(Gn + f)^{2}} > 0$ , and when  we substitute in the latter ones $n = \frac{pG - fk}{Gk}$ we arrive at $-k (1- \frac{fk}{pG}) > 0$ leading to $p < \frac{fk}{G}$ ,so when $p < \frac{fk}{G}$, the fixed point is unstable .

$Case-2$

when $$n^{*} = 0$$

And now for $n^{*} = 0$ , substituting in the expression of $f^{'}$ above we get $\frac{Gp}{f} - k > 0$ implies for $p > (p_{c} = \frac{kf}{G})$ , $n^{*} = 0$ is an unstable fixed point.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Sorry,Will edit soon!

Comment: How it is ? , when we put $n = 0,$ we get $-\frac{G^{2}.0.p}{(G.0 + f)^{2}} = 0$ @infinitylord

Comment: @dbliss $\frac{Gp}{Gn + f} = \frac{Gp}{G.(\frac{pG-fk}{Gk}) + f} =  \frac{Gp}{\frac{pG- fk + fk}{k}} = \frac{Gpk}{pG} = k$...are there any mistakes here ?

Comment: oh.. I actually did for both fixed points ..ok, now i have divided them into cases , hope it is now clear!@dbliss